# ScrollTo Top not working

Tags: jquery

Im struggling to get my scrollTo Top working.

Here is my css code for the button:

```
.scrollTop {    
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #959595;
    bottom: 10%;
    position: fixed;
    right: 10px;
    z-index: 999;
    display:none;
}
.scrollTop a{   
    background:url(../images/to-top.png) no-repeat center center #959595;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    text-indent:-9999px;
}
.scrollTop a:hover{
    background-color:#e00a16;
}
```

Here is the jQuery that performs the function:

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) { $('.scrollTop').fadeIn(); } else { $('.scrollTop').fadeOut(); }
    });

    $('.scrollTop').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 800);
        return false;
    });
```

Its not showing up at all, its almost as if the css style isnt picking up the image, but it is linked corectly. I have tried suggestions on the forums here but none seem to be working.
This is all done in wordpress.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: Works fine in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/y8F5W/. Check your console for errors.

Comment: Works fine [indeed](http://jsfiddle.net/u2czS/). Make sure jQuery is not conflicting with other libraries.

Comment: try wrapping in `jQuery(document).ready(function($) { // YOUR CODE HERE });`

Comment: Thanks for the help guys!! There was an error in my script.js file. It ran until it encountered this error. Corrected it and its now working 100%. Thanks again :)